# Python: how to create list of objects that are subset from another

Tags: python, oop

I have a class called `Reader` which is composed as follows:

```py
class Reader:
    name = None
    id = None

reader1 = Reader(name='Entrance', id=1)
reader2 = Reader(name='Exit', id=2)
reader3 = Reader(name='Hallway', id=3)
reader4 = Reader(name='Reception', id=4)
```

Then I have another class called `Doorgroup` which is composed of `Reader` objects

```py
class Doorgroup:
    name = None
    readers = []

doorgroup1 = Doorgroup(name='Borders', readers=[reader1, reader2])
doorgroup2 = Doorgroup(name='Insides', readers=[reader3, reader4])
doorgroup3 = Doorgroup(name='Admin', readers=[reader1, reader2, reader3, reader4])
doorgroup4 = Doorgroup(name='IN', readers=[reader1, reader3, reader4])
doorgroup5 = Doorgroup(name='OUT', readers=[reader2])
```

Now I have arrays of `int` representing the `reader` ids that I want to convert to `Doorgroup` instances.

For example:
`[1, 2]` would return `[doorgroup1, doorgroup3, doorgroup5]` since `[1, 2]` are a part  of `reader`s of `doorgroup1`, `doorgroup3` and `[2]` is part of `doorgroup5`

I am new to python but Is there a way where I can implement this logic?

Comment: Should we assume you decorated `Reader` with `@dataclasses.dataclass` or something? Because as written, with no `__init__`, none of this code will run (you can't pass arguments to `Reader` because it inherits a useless default `__init__` that knows nothing of `name` or `id`). Regardless, please add enough to this to make it runnable; we need a [MCVE] to work with.

Comment: Also, side-note, you should really just store a `list` of your instances (or possibly `dict` mapping `id` or `name` to instances), not a bunch of variables with numerically increasing names. It's *much* easier to work with collections than to try to programmatically work with a variable number of named variables.

Comment: And `reader1` is a member of `doorgroup4` so your expected output should be `[doorgroup1, doorgroup3, doorgroup4, doorgroup5]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `Reader` objects in that way, then you will need to create an `__init__` method with `name` and `id` as arguments (as well as `self`). Similarly for `Doorgroup` objects. See the below class definitions.

Rather than having `reader1`, `reader2`, and so on as separate variables, it would be easier to create a dictionary (a container of `key: value` pairs) whereby each `key` denotes the number of the reader (e.g. `1` or `2` or `3` and so on) and `value` is the corresponding `Reader` instance. Similarly for `Doorgroup` objects.

The following code makes the above changes. If I have interpreted your question correctly, it also achieves your desired translation from a list of ids to a list of `Doorgroup` objects. In my implementation, the final 'list' of `Doorgroup` objects is in fact a `set` but you can easily convert it to a list via `list()` if you need a list instead. The reason that we use a `set` (a container of distinct hashable objects) is because it guarantees that a  `Doorgroup` object will not be added if it is already inside the set.

Please let me know if there are any questions! I hope that this helps.

```
class Reader:
    def __init__(self, name = None, id = None):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

class Doorgroup:
    def __init__(self, name = None, readers = []):
        self.name = name
        self.readers = readers

# create instances of Reader, store them in dict where a key is an id
# and the associated value is a Reader instance
readers = {}
readers[1] = Reader(name = 'Entrance', id = 1)
readers[2] = Reader(name = 'Exit', id = 2)
readers[3] = Reader(name = 'Hallway', id = 3)
readers[4] = Reader(name = 'Reception', id = 4)

# create instances of Doorgroup, store them in a dict where a key is the
# Doorgroup instance number and the value is a Doorgroup instance
dgroups = {}
dgroups[1] = Doorgroup(name = 'Borders', readers = [readers[1], readers[2]])
dgroups[2] = Doorgroup(name = 'Insides', readers = [readers[3], readers[4]])
dgroups[3] = Doorgroup(name = 'Admin', readers = [readers[1], readers[2],
    readers[3], readers[4]])
dgroups[4] = Doorgroup(name = 'IN', readers = [readers[1], readers[3],
    readers[4]])
dgroups[5] = Doorgroup(name = 'OUT', readers = [readers[2]])

# Convert list of ids to set of Doorgroup instances
ids = [1, 2]
result = set()

for key in dgroups:
    for i in ids:
        if readers[i] in dgroups[key].readers:
            result.add((key, dgroups[key]))

print(result)
```

Output

```
{(4, <__main__.Doorgroup object at 0x7fabe5857ca0>), (5, <__main__.Doorgroup object at 0x7fabe5857c40>), (3, <__main__.Doorgroup object at 0x7fabe5857d00>), (1, <__main__.Doorgroup object at 0x7fabe5857dc0>)}
```

The output set has elements that are 2-tuples whereby the 1st element of each 2-tuple denotes the number of the Doorgroup instance. You didn't ask for this number but I have included it as it is useful for verifying that the code works.